# Database connection in c#.net VS2010

Tags: c#, database, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to my database in .net using dataset. My code is for a workbook creator. The method takes the questions form the DB and put them in list. When I'm running the code I get the next error:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 103.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
       at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
       at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString, Boolean validate)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(String connectionString, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.ConnectionString_Set(String value)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter..ctor(String selectCommandText, String selectConnectionString)
       at bookPage.getPageDB() in c:\Users\asaf_pearl\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\bookreator\App_Code\question.cs:line 188
       at book.Page_init(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\asaf_pearl\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\bookreator\book.aspx.cs:line 23
       at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:
```

the code is :

```
public void getPageDB( )
{
    string ConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data   
     Source=C:\\Users\\asaf_pearl\\Documents\\Visual Studio 
     2010\\WebSites\bookreator\\App_Data/bookretorDB1.accdb" + ";";
    string myQuery = "select from fivebaloons where page=1";

    OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter   (myQuery, ConnStr);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    oda.Fill(ds);
    foreach(DataRow pRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows){

        _currentQuest.question=pRow["question"].ToString();
        _currentQuest.questionNumber =Convert.ToInt16( pRow["questionnumber"]);
        _currentQuest.rightAnswer=pRow["answer"].ToString();
        _currentQuest.goodFeedBack=pRow["goodfeedback"].ToString();
        _currentQuest.badFeedBack1=pRow["badfeedback1"].ToString();
        _currentQuest.badFeedBack2=pRow["badfeedback2"].ToString();
        AllQuestions.Add(_currentQuest);
    }
}
```

can you tell me whats wrong ? ( in another code its working)

Comment: Whats the difference between this and the code its working? Obviously, there's a slight difference in the connection string.

Answer (score 1):

It is telling you where the error is: at index 103 in your initialization, i.e. connection string.

> ... Format of the initialization string does not conform to
>   specification starting at index 103 ...

The code formatting in your question doesn't allow for an exact counting of characters, but most likely it is because you used a single backslash (instead of an escaped one like everywhere else) for

```
string connStr = "... WebSites\bookreator ...";
```

Change it to

```
string connStr = "... WebSite\\bookreator ...";
```

Note: The (forward) slash in this fragment "`App_Data/bookretorDB1.accdb`" should be OK, as Windows APIs typically accept it as a directory separator as well. You may want to, at least for consistency, use a `\\` here as well.

Answer (score 0):

try to write connection string like this

```
string constr = string.Format( "Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=SSPI", YourServerName,YourDatabaseName);
```